# Finding the number of abelian groups of order 10

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Find the number of abelian groups of order $10$.

So I tried using the abelian fundamental theorem..
You can write $10= 2 \times 5$
But $p(1)*p(1)=1$. So is there only one abelian group of order $10$?
With $ \mathbb{Z} _{10} $ isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z} _{2} \times \mathbb{Z} _{5}$? I think I have an understanding issue here.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, there **is** only one.